# Two rejects in One Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am new to JavaScript. I don't know where I can use two rejects inside one promise; can anyone tell me that it's bad practice to have two rejects in one promise? If yes, what will be the optional solution?

Here is my code

```
async handler(ctx) {
                /*
                 * sheet_to_json method converts excel file to JSON format
                */
                let { s3Url, header } = ctx.params;
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    request({method: 'GET',  uri: s3Url,encoding: null}, async function(err, res, data) {
                        if(err || res.statusCode !== 200) reject(err);
                        try{
                            const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type:'buffer'});
                            const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
                            let result = await XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]], {header});
                            resolve(result);
                        }
                        catch(error){
                            reject("Invalid File Cointaint");
                        }       
                    })
                });
            }
```

Comment: Only the first reject will do anything. Once a Promise has been rejected it can't be rejected or resolved again (calling `reject` or `resolve` again is harmless, but does nothing); it is permanently in the rejected state. You should probably return early: `return reject(err);` so that the rest of the code doesn't run in the function after you reject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple places that you call `reject(err)` inside your promise callback.  Only the first one to execute will matter.  Subsequent calls to `reject()` are ignored because once the Promise state is set, it cannot be changed by further calls to `reject()` or `resolve()`.

It is generally good practice to end your function execution with a `return` or to use an `else` statement when you reject since continuing to do other stuff that isn't going to resolve or reject is usually meaningless and in some cases harmful.

So, in your specific case, you can either add a `return` like this:

```
async handler(ctx) {
    /*
     * sheet_to_json method converts excel file to JSON format
     */
    let {s3Url,header} = ctx.params;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({method: 'GET', uri: s3Url, encoding: null}, async function(err, res, data) {
            if (err || res.statusCode !== 200) return reject(err); // <==== return added here
            try {
                const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'buffer'});
                const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
                let result = await XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]], {header});
                resolve(result);
            } catch (error) {
                reject("Invalid File Cointaint");
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Or, you can add an else:

```
async handler(ctx) {
    /*
     * sheet_to_json method converts excel file to JSON format
     */
    let {s3Url, header} = ctx.params;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({method: 'GET', uri: s3Url, encoding: null}, async function(err, res, data) {
            if (err || res.statusCode !== 200) {
                reject(err);
            } else {           // <======== else added here
                try {
                    const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'buffer'});
                    const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
                    let result = await XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]], {header});
                    resolve(result);
                } catch (error) {
                    reject("Invalid File Cointaint");
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use any number of `reject` in a promise. Just the rejects need to be on different flow. Means calling one `reject` after another `reject` won't work. As calling one `resolve` after another `resolve` won't.

Also to make sure other code doesn't run it is good idea to add a `return` before the `reject`.

For example:

```
const checkIfRightPermission = new Promise((res, rej) =>{
    //let's say we are doing an http request.
    request.get('/getPermission?id=someid', function(err, res, body){
        if(err){
            //the request itself couldn't be completed SO
            return rej();
        }else{
            if(sufficientPermission(body)){

            }else{
                //again
                return rej()
            }
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep each resolve and reject in a if else block.

```
if (condition1) {
  resolve(true);
} else if (condition2) {
  reject(false);
} else {
  reject(false);
}
```

For example if you were going to do this:

```
if (condition1) {
  resolve(true);
}
reject(false);
```

You should instead:

```
if (condition1) {
  resolve(true);
  return;
}
reject(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to use many rejects, it totally depends of your logic and it was made to be used in this way.

The only thing I suggest you to change is the try/catch block inside the Promise, when you thrown an exception the next promise.catch will handle it.

Take a look:

https://medium.com/datafire-io/es6-promises-patterns-and-anti-patterns-bbb21a5d0918